# How can i update an activity in android studio

Tags: android

I've created an app with two activities. On the second activity i can create new buttons by pressing a floating action bar button inside the activity; but the problems is when i return to the main activity and come back all the added buttons are gone.

I was wondering how can i save these added views so whenever i exit that particular activity or the app entirely, views won't perish.

I know i can save the views' values by "Preferences" commands but that only can save the views' parameters not themselves and if i go that way i have to recreate each view again each time i enter the activity.

if i could update the activity whenever views are added to it that would be excellent.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Preferences is the only way, when you exit the Activity everything gets destroyed.

Comment: as @cmak said , sharedPreferences  can help you , or if you want to save more data , use sqlite : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Comment: To answer to your question may not be SharedPreferences. If you provide more detailed information and share the code, we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

You can save information about views  in preference like number of buttons created. for example you clicked button 4 times then save numOfButtons value as 4. In onCreate method you can check values of numOfButtons and execute that block of code 4 times to generate buttons.